# Issue with lapply

Tags: r

Printing the value of data.frame within lapply but outside it does not retain the values.

```
lapply(names(RFEresults), function(x)
   {
     feats <- extractFeatures(RFEresults[[x]])
     featurestat[which(featurestat[, 1]==x),rownames(feats)] <- feats$time.choosen
     print(featurestat[1, ])
   })

print(featurestat[1, ])
```

Does lapply do not retain values?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the result you're getting? Does it work when you do it "manually"? Side note: I suggest you pass `RFEresults` into your `lapply` call.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I need to use names to index. print function call prints the featurestat correctly but the same outside of lapply prints the original data.frame. featurestat is initialize with 0's.

Comment: @Shahzad objects modified inside a function are modified in the function environment. When you exit the function, the environment is not the same, so your changes are lost. If you provide a reproducible example we may be able to help you with your code.

Comment: A reproducible example is the best way to go, but if you're not able to provide us with one, at least show us what your objects look like (`str` or first five rows and columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#assign result of the lapply loop to an object
res <- lapply(names(RFEresults), function(x)
   {
     feats <- extractFeatures(RFEresults[[x]])
     featurestat[which(featurestat[, 1]==x),rownames(feats)] <- feats$time.choosen
     featurestat #return value of the function
   })

#now you have the results of each iteration in a list
#and can access them using
print(res[[1]])
print(res[[2]])
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's kosher but this should work:

```
 lapply(names(RFEresults), function(x)
 {
    feats <- extractFeatures(RFEresults[[x]])
    featurestat[which(featurestat[, 1]==x),rownames(feats)] <<- feats$time.choosen
    print(featurestat[1, ])
 })
```